# REST Services - Do I really have to read the OperationContext to get the message?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, httprequest

I'm trying to create a sample REST-service and a client.
I'm quite shocked, because it seems that I can only ready the messagebody over a hack, the operationContext:

```
var ctx = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage;
```

So I can just send primitive types over the URI and have to go over the context to read the xml data? Since it seems I can just select xml or json as body, I have to work with one of these.
So all I can pass directly are primitive types over the URI?

Which leads me to the question: Is it not the idea of REST to pass complex types but primitives over the URI? Or is there a easier solution I didn't find yet?

Comment: Are you using WCF? If yes I would recomend WEB API as it has been designed with REST in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make restful services you should consider using WCF Restful services. They are easy and Robust. You can see a tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services)

Comment: As long as we have WEB API, I wouldn't consider the use of WCF in this case.

Comment: I guess I got it: I can read the body by adding a Stream to the function or at the Context. The question is ofc, if the clients can consume this proper.